# How would my phone knows I'm driving?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-535

Very often, my L535DS shows the below screenshot:

[image]

I can confirm that it doesn't have any such sensors. And it shows up the same screen most of the time when I'm watching some video. Is it a bug or something? As it becomes very annoying when I saw the screen two to three times in a 18 minutes video.

Comment: I'm guessing it has some type of GPS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Driving Mode automatically starts when your associated bluetooth device is connected to your device. As Microsoft states in this [document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027107/windows-set-up-driving-mode-in-windows-10-mobile)

> Once you set up a device, driving mode will automatically start
>   whenever your phone connects to the device

This is the bluetooth device you selected while configuring driving mode for the first time.

Comment: Oh and I thought its because of some motion sensors or something alike... Well it's true that my phone is always connected to Bluetooth headset when I'm watching videos ... 